# How to correctly get RIGHT KEYSEQ for readline in .inputrc?

Tags: keyboard-layout, shortcut-keys, input

### What I struggle with:

I'm configuring `~/.inputrc` file to be same as mine custom emacs key-bindings and I'm struggling very much with readline's key sequences.

What I mean by that is that if I want to set `<up>` / `<down>`, I have to set it to `"\e[A"` / `"\e[B"`

How can I  infer keyseq for `<F1>..<F12>` or even if I want to bind something to let's say `(kbd "C-x <M-f7>")` in emacs terminology (ie: to `[control]+[x] [alt]+[f7]` be one keyseq)?

---

### What I want:

Is there any **command** that tells me for certain key on keyboard what its escape sequence? If there isn't any command, is there any other resource (article/table/...) with some hints?

```
--> goal: replace <KEY SEQUENCE> with proper keyseq

"<f3>"           : start-kbd-macro
"<S-f4>"         : end-kbd-macro
"C-x <C-M-S-f4>" : dump-macro
"<f4>"           : call-last-kbd-macro
... more keybindings ...
```

---

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found solution: use `emacs -nw` and function `insert-quoted` (default bind to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd>).

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd> <kbd>↑</kbd> will result in `^[[A`
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd> <kbd>F1</kbd> in `^[[[A`

Lines in `~/.inputrc` will then be following (results may vary depending on environment  - mostly $TERM variable):

```
"\e[[A": "pressed up key"
"\e[[[A": "pressed F1"
```

---

Motivation to change your .inputrc can be following.

Don't you like emacs-like keys for navigating along line and history?
I don't and I prefer [ErgoEmacs](https://ergoemacs.github.io/) key bindings because they are logical and I want to use them not only in Emacs but system wide.

```
"\ej": backward-char
"\el": forward-char
"\ei": previous-history
"\ek": next-history
"\eh": beginning-of-line
"\eH": end-of-line
"\eu": backward-word
"\eo": forward-word
"\eg": kill-line
"\eG": backward-kill-line
"\ee": backward-kill-word
"\er": kill-word
"\ed": backward-delete-char
"\ef": delete-char
"\ez": undo
"\ex": kill-region
"\ec": copy-region-as-kill
"\ev": yank
"\e;": forward-search-history
"\e:": reverse-search-history
```

I have written "sudo aptitude install" so many times (usually after fresh install) that I have `M-a M-i` (ie <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>) as shortcut for that (because `alias` to same thing don't autocomplete)

```
"\ea\ei": "sudo aptitude install "
```

---

There are plenty other reasons why you should have your own `~/.inputrc` ...

Answer (score 1):

## Vim readline filetype & syntax

I found that [Vim](https://www.vim.org/) has a readline filetype plugin, which can help to rewrite your `.inputrc`.

The plugin should auto-detect `.inputrc`, and if not you can call `:set filetype=readline` to select it.

Assuming you have an empty line such as `"": readline-command` you can place your cursor inside the "" quotes in insert-mode (<kbd>i</kbd>) and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> then <kbd>keystroke-combination</kbd> to insert many of the more magical incantations.

Assuming syntax completion is on you can auto-complete readline commands.